# How to change uint16_t to two uint8_t?

Tags: c++, bit-shift, masking

How to convert one uint16_t to two parts?

```
uint16_t value = 0x7133;
uint8_t partA = (uint8_t)((value & 0xFF00) >> 8);
uint8_t partB = (uint8_t)(value & 0x00FF);
std::cout << std::hex << partA << std::endl; 
std::cout << std::hex << partB << std::endl;
```

For the above code I get `partA` as `q` and `partB` as `3` instead of `0x71` and `0x33`.

Comment: std::hex does not have any effect ?

Comment: It is also easy to avoid  "warning: use of old-style cast to ... } [-Wold-style-cast]"> (I'm sure we all turn on this warning!) I prefer a one line function (containing the cast) to convert, such as "uint  scu(uint b) { return static_cast<uint>(b); }"  The use of uint support auto-promotion ... so it only takes a few funcs.

Comment: @2785528 `uint scu(uint b) { return static_cast<uint>(b); }` is entirely useless. Just write static casts instead of hiding them behind some obscurely named (and possibly wrong) functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Putting a `uint8_t` into `cout` gets the `operator<<(const char&)` picked which prints letters and 71 and 33 happen to be the ascii codes of `q` and `3`. If you want to see the number, you have to make it pick a different overload:

```
uint16_t value = 0x7133;
uint8_t partA = static_cast<uint8_t>((value & 0xFF00) >> 8);
uint8_t partB = static_cast<uint8_t>(value & 0x00FF);
std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<int>(partA) << std::endl; 
std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<int>(partB) << std::endl;
```

> std::hex does not have any effect

It does have an effect, but not on letters. There is no hex formatting applied for eg `q`. Once you pick an overload that prints numbers the numbers will be printed as hex.

PS: I changed your c-style casts to `static_cast`s. C-style casts are a red flag, and they should make you panic, because most often they are just hiding a bug.

Comment: ...there's a duplicate for this. Let's not repeat this same answer every time the question comes up.

Comment: @Max if you find it i'll happily delete this

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the conversion in a right way. The confusing output is the result of `uint8_t` being the same type as `char` on your platform. Try changing your code to

```
  std::cout << std::hex << (uint16_t)partA << std::endl; 
  std::cout << std::hex << (uint16_t)partB << std::endl;
```

And you will see

```
71
33
```

Comment: This also can cause 2x:  warning: use of old-style cast to ‘uint16_t’ {aka ‘short unsigned int’} [-Wold-style-cast]